# How do i Fix this Username and Password?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def Hello_World():
    print('Enter correct combonation to continue:')
    allowed_users = ['Bill', 'Sherly', 'Jim']
number=0
while number<4:     
        username = input("Username:")
        password = input("Password:")
if username in allowed_users and password=='Family':

        print("Access granted")
        number=5 
else:
        print("Access denied")
        number=4
```

My question is that I don't like that when I run it the code it calls the function Hello_World() automatically and I would rather like to call upon it myself so I'm can put it into another function kinda like:

```
def all_together():
Hello_World()
Keep_going():
```

So then I call the function all_together() and then I'm okay. Also when i use this all it does is go straight to the while statement and skips over the print right below Hello_World(): How do I stop that from happening. And the last thing is when I use this code all it does is ask for Username,(then I type it is perfectly fine), then Password(then I type that in) but after that, it just repeats the asking for the username and password and doesn't stop how do I get it to keep going on to something else, like my other function Keep_going():

(btw I do have my function Keep_going() defined already I just left that out for the sake of space.) **COULD YOU SHOW ME HOW TO DO IT?**

Comment: One more question, is there a way to take a function in the same folder on another notepad and use it with a different function on a different notepad?

Comment: you have indentation problem. Your function ends after allowed_user statement. Also while loop ends after asking for password, number remains same so infinite loop

Comment: There are Python tutorials available at python.org.